# How to avoid using A.self?

Tags: swift

Take this code:

```
protocol P: class {
static var hello: String { get }
}

class A: P {
    class var hello: String {
        return "Hello"
    }
}

class B: A {
    override static var hello: String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}

class C: A {}

class D: C {
    override static var hello: String {
        return "Hello D"
    }
}

func sayHello(elements: P.Type...) {
    for p in elements {
        print(p.hello)
    }
}

func sayHelloAgain(elements: A.Type...) {
    for p in elements {
        print(p.hello)
    }
}

func sayHelloThe3rd(elements: [A.Type]) {
    for p in elements {
        print(p.hello)
    }
}

sayHello(A.self, B.self, C.self)
sayHelloAgain(A.self, B.self, C.self)
```

Compare it to this (taken from this [presentation](https://realm.io/news/appbuilders-natasha-muraschev-practical-protocol-oriented-programming/))

```
func register<T: UITableViewCell where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView>(_: T.Type) { ... }
tableView.register(FoodTableViewCell)
```

Why do I have to use A.self in one case, but not in the other?
And also, don't need to use .self when calling with one argument.

```
sayHello(A)
sayHello(A, B) //doesn't compile
```

Comment: The older code you're referencing now generates a warning that you should add `.self`. There were cases in earlier versions of Swift where the `.self` could be guessed and the compiler would stick it in, but Swift is moving to always require it as Alexander notes below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.self` is syntactic salt. It's not necessary from a technical perspective, but it exists to cause errors in code that's often a result of a typo, such as:

```
struct Foo { }

let foo = Foo
```

This code will give you a compiler error, telling you that either you need to complete the initializer/function/method call, or append `.self` if you meant to refer to the type.

In the latter example, the context deals exclusively with types and not values, so there's no chance of confusing one with the other, thus, `.self` isn't necessary.

Perhaps there's a way to modify the function declaration in your example so as to not require the `.self`, but I'm not aware of such a feature. I'd be interested to find out.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the term syntactic salt.

Comment: @LescaiIonel Yep, most languages have them. For example, Swift requires the `fallthrough` keyword in switch statements, to avoid accidental implicit fallthough. `var` is also syntactic salt to inform users of potentially unwanted mutation, but it also makes code intent clearer.