# Swift 3, is the ".self" in a metatype issue actually correct?

Tags: generics, swift3, metatype

I have an extension to walk up the view controller chain (even through container views, which is very handy)

```
public extension UIViewController   // go up to a certain class
    {
    public func above<T>(_ : T.Type)->(T)
        {
        var p:UIResponder = self
        repeat { p = p.next! } while !(p is T)
        return p as! T
        }
    }
```

*(Aside, NB, Swift3 needs the "!" on p.next: unfortunately I'm not sure exactly why.)*

So, say you have a view controller class "General", you can

```
self.above(General).clickedHamburgerMenuButton()
```

and it will find the first "General" above you.  All fine but with Swift 3 you get this warning.......

> Missing '.self' for reference to metatype of type 'General'

It seems to want this

```
self.above(General.self).clickedHamburgerMenuButton()
```

1) It seems ... dangerous ... to change `General` to `General.self` - in fact is it safe and is the **meaning the same** as `General` in Swift <3 ?

2) in the extension

```
    public func above<T>(_ : T.Type)->(T)
```

why is that a metatype?  Did I "do something wrong" **and make it ask for a metatype** rather than just a type?

2) What the hell is a "metatype"?  (I can't, really, find it explained as such anywhere.)  That is to say, what can "general" possibly mean there other than "the class itself".  (Not an instance, or a static instance, or anything else...)

Comment: Being able to omit `.self` for single argument functions was a bug pre-Swift 3, see [swift class as parameter without .self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869950/swift-class-as-parameter-without-self). Also see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838722/how-to-avoid-using-a-self) about why `.self` is needed. As for info about metatypes, [see this part of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455) :). In your example, `T.Type` is the metatype

Comment: thanks @Hamish, that is a beautiful and information dense comment  :)

Comment: Btw, of course your method can be written without forced unwrapping, and note that it would crash if no matching responder is found.

Comment: Hi @MartinR -  thanks for that. if I ever totally understand what "forced unwrapping" is, I will be able to start understanding your comment .. :-) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Aside, NB, Swift3 needs the "!" on p.next: unfortunately I'm not sure exactly why.)

Because `.next` returns an Optional, but `p` is not optional. This will crash if you run out of responders.

> 1) It seems ... dangerous ... to change General to General.self - in fact is it safe and is the meaning the same as General in Swift <3 ?

I'm surprised that worked in earlier versions of Swift without the `.self`, but yes, `.self` is required in order to directly reference a metatype. Referencing metatypes is somewhat rare in Swift, and can lead to surprising behaviors if done unintentionally, so it requires an extra piece of syntax to say "yes, I really mean the type."

> why is that a metatype? Did I "do something wrong" and make it ask for a metatype rather than just a type?

You did this correctly.

> 2) What the hell is a "metatype"?

The type of a type. An instance of a metatype is a type. Consider:

```
func f(x: Int)
```

To call this, you pass an instance of `Int`. So similarly:

```
func f<T>(x: T.Type)
```

To call this, you pass an instance of the metatype `T.Type`, which is a type.

---

Unrelated, but I would probably rethink this code along these lines. First, it is convenient to be able to treat the responder chain as a sequence. Here's one way to do that:

```
public extension UIResponder {
    public func nextResponders() -> AnySequence<UIResponder> {
        guard let first = next else { return AnySequence([]) }
        return AnySequence(sequence(first: first, next: { $0.next }))
    }
}
```

Then getting the next responder that matches a type is cleaner and clearer IMO (and works on any responder chain):

```
public extension UIResponder {
    public func firstResponder<T: UIResponder>(ofType _: T.Type)-> T? {
        return nextResponders()
            .flatMap { $0 as? T }
            .first
    }
}

...

self.firstResponder(ofType: General.self)?.clickedHamburgerMenuButton()
```

Comment: TBC if I'm no tmistaken your **nextResponders** in fact returns THE WHOLE RESPONDER CHAIN .. all classes.  (Indeed, using recursion there.)  Then, your **firstResponder** simply picks out all of the desired class (the flatMap) and just returns the first one of those (.first).  Awesome

Comment: Yes, `nextResponders` returns the entire responder chain lazily (so it doesn't actually compute the entire chain until they're requested). It's not recursive, though; `sequence` is iterative.

Comment: oh I see ... `next: { $0.next }` is putting in all of them ... wild